# loop through elements of array within an object within another array

Tags: javascript

```
var data = [
  {
    Name: "HR",
    popularity: 91,
    keywords: ["bat", "happy", "success"]
  },
  {
    Name: "biz",
    popularity: 3,
    keywords: ["sad", "code", "shady"]
  },
  {
    Name: "xyz",
    popularity: 80,
    keywords: ["alphabetical", "code", "trendy"]
  },
  {
    Name: "catty",
    popularity: 536,
    keywords: ["code", "startup", "cats"]
  }
];
```

How would I write that function that simply returns all the keywords in one array, regardless of how many objects I add or delete to the data array? I don't want to manually concat each unless I can use a loop.

I mainly want to write a function that can test whether any word is in any of the keywords of the data set and then return it's name or names.

Comment: What have you tried, where did you have a problem?

Comment: I know how to figure it out if i know exactly which data[i].keywords Im testing. I find myself getting false positives if I want to test if any word im testing is in any of the keywords.

Comment: It doesn't really bring you anything to concat the keywords, if you have no link back to the original object, why not create a dictionary which key is based on the keyword, and holds the objects in an array as the value

Comment: So you will stop searching at the first occurrence, or continue and collect all object names that have a keyword match?

Comment: Im looking for a way to collect all the object names but with a string input, not an array. Separately, I would also like a function that gives a boolean output of whether the word is in any of the keyword arrays.

Comment: I would say that [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) sound like the tools you want. But then I get a conflicting description when you say that want a boolean. Are you able to write a pseudo description for your requirement?

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't really bring you anything to concat the keywords, if you have no link back to the original object, why not create a dictionary which key is based on the keyword, and holds the objects in an array as the value.

It's then very easy to create a search to return results based on 1 keyword

```js
var data = [
  {
    Name: "HR",
    popularity: 91,
    keywords: ["bat", "happy", "success"]
  },
  {
    Name: "biz",
    popularity: 3,
    keywords: ["sad", "code", "shady"]
  },
  {
    Name: "xyz",
    popularity: 80,
    keywords: ["alphabetical", "code", "trendy"]
  },
  {
    Name: "catty",
    popularity: 536,
    keywords: ["code", "startup", "cats"]
  }
];

function createKeywordSet( data ) {
  return data.reduce( (dict, arrayItem) => {
    arrayItem.keywords.forEach( keyword => {
      if (!dict[keyword]) {
        dict[keyword] = [];
      }
      dict[keyword].push( arrayItem );
    } );
    return dict;
  }, {});
}

function findByKeyword( keywordSet, keyword ) {
  return keywordSet[keyword] || [];
}

let set = createKeywordSet( data );

console.log( findByKeyword( set, 'code' ).map( r => r.Name ) );
console.log( findByKeyword( set, 'startup' ).map( r => r.Name ) );
console.log( findByKeyword( set, 'keyword' ).map( r => r.Name ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **map**() js function on an array.
What it does: it takes every single element of the array and executs a function.

Here is the code below that will get all the keywords and put them in the array allKeywords:

```
var allKeywords=[];

data.map((x)=>(allKeywords = allKeywords.concat(x.keywords)));

console.log(allKeywords);
```

The array allKeywords now has the following:

```
['bat','happy','success','sad','code','shady','alphabetical','code','trendy','code','startup','cats' ]
```

*What happened?*

1. I use data.map(**x => x.keywords** ...): to get all the inner arrays of keywords.
2. I concatenate all inner lists together to give the final output.

This is a functional programming way of thinking.
If you need any help understanding let me know.

Try it out!! Read a little about the map function. It is very useful.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score -1):

A possibility, but not the only one.

[Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[Array#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
function getNames(arrayOfObjects, searchKeyword) {
  return arrayOfObjects.filter((object) => {
    return object.keywords.includes(searchKeyword);
  }).map((object) => object.Name);
}

function includesKeyword(arrayOfObjects, searchKeyword) {
  return getNames(arrayOfObjects, searchKeyword).length > 0;
}

const data = [{
    Name: "HR",
    popularity: 91,
    keywords: ["bat", "happy", "success"]
  },
  {
    Name: "biz",
    popularity: 3,
    keywords: ["sad", "code", "shady"]
  },
  {
    Name: "xyz",
    popularity: 80,
    keywords: ["alphabetical", "code", "trendy"]
  },
  {
    Name: "catty",
    popularity: 536,
    keywords: ["code", "startup", "cats"]
  }
];

console.log(getNames(data, 'code'));
console.log(getNames(data, 'happy'));
console.log(getNames(data, 'wibble'));
console.log(includesKeyword(data, 'code'));
console.log(includesKeyword(data, 'wibble'));
```

Welcome to SO, in future try to provide examples of what you have tried and a full description of the problems that you are experiencing. Pseudo code is welcome if you have nothing else.

Comment: When marking an answer down, leaving  comment as to why would be appreciated!